# What notification do I get when a view appears in iphone?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, infinite-loop

I want to know what notification would I get in my CustomView class when this view will be displayed on screen.

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
NewViewController *newController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

and after some work I pop this viewController.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I want to know what method in CustomView class will be called when that view will appear again on the screen.

Actually I have an infinite loop animation in that CustomView and on pushing to nextController I have to stop that animation loop and after coming back I need to start it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIView doesn't get

```
viewWillAppear
viewDidDisappear 
etc
```

ViewController in which it's contained, however, does, so, in order to pass it to UIView you are to implement following method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] viewWIllAppear]; // i assume your subview is the only one, otherwise you need to know the index, or have it as an ivar/property 
}
```

Another idea - since you use your view a lot, i assume you do not recreate it. Let it be a property of your [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]. Now you can access it like this:

```
#define SharedView [(appDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedView];
```

Then make custom UIViewController and overwrite viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  if ( [SharedView.superview isEqual:self.view] )
  {
     [SharedView viewWillAppear];
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using this view in many places in my application so viewWillAppear of viewController doesn't seem right, if you have any other option that would be superb.

Answer (score 1):

You answered it yourself.

```
viewWillAppear
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at: [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)

```
Observing View-Related Changes
– didAddSubview:
– willRemoveSubview:
– willMoveToSuperview:
– didMoveToSuperview
– willMoveToWindow:
– didMoveToWindow
```